# Calculating Time Intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the amount of time a vehicle parks between certain times, 6:00 AM-18:00 PM and 18:00 PM-6:00 AM. I can successfully calculate the amount of time a vehicle parked from 6:00 AM-18:00 PM and 18:00 PM-11:59 PM. As soon as the time crosses over pass 11:59 PM (to 12:00 AM) it can no longer calculate.

Vehicle CSV:

```
vehicle    park_start_time     park_end_time      duration    enforce_time_1      enforce_time_2
car1       2/10/2018 14:13      2/10/2018 14:20    7          6:00 to 18:00        18:00 to 6:00
car2       2/2/2018 11:06       2/3/2018 19:17     1931       6:00 to 18:00        18:00 to 6:00
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('vehicle.csv', sep=';')
test = df
test['Start_Enforce_1'] = test['enforced_time_1'].str.split().str[0].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
test['Finish_Enforce_1'] = test['enforced_time_1'].str.split().str[-1].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)

test['Start_Enforce_2'] = test['enforced_time_2'].str.split().str[0].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
test['Finish_Enforce_2'] = test['enforced_time_2'].str.split().str[-1].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)


def check_time(df_line):
    max_hours = float(df_line['max time'])
    dt_range = pd.date_range(start = df_line['Parked_from'], end=df_line['Parked_to'], freq='1Min')
    return np.sum((dt_range.hour >= (df_line['Start_Enforce_1'])) & (dt_range.hour < df_line['Finish_Enforce_1']))
def check_time_2(df_line):
    max_hours = float(df_line['max time'])
    dt_range = pd.date_range(start = df_line['Parked_from'], end=df_line['Parked_to'], freq='1Min')
    return np.sum((dt_range.hour >= (df_line['Start_Enforce_2'])) & (dt_range.hour < df_line['Finish_Enforce_2']))

test['6am to 18pm'] = test.apply(check_time, axis=1)
test['18pm to 6am'] = test.apply(check_time_2, axis=1)
test.to_csv("result.csv", sep=';', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Result:

```
vehicle;park_start_time;park_end_time;duration;enforced_time_1;enforced_time_2;Start_Enforce_1;Finish_Enforce_1;Start_Enforce_2;Finish_Enforce_2;6am to 18pm;18pm to 6am
car1;2/10/2018 14:13;2/10/2018 14:20;7;6:00 to 18:00;18:00 to 6:00;6;18;18;6;8;0
car2;2/2/2018 11:06;2/3/2018 19:17;1931;6:00 to 18:00;18:00 to 6:00;6;18;18;6;1134;0
```

As you can see for **car2** only the parked time during 6 AM to 18 pm is captured for **1134 minutes** parked. 
Any ideas or suggestions on how to capture the remaining time after 11:59 PM would be appreciated.

Comment: Can’t you just add 18:00-00:00 and 00:00-06:00?

Comment: will you always 6to18 and 18to6 or it is just for the example? also for car1, you have 8 in the column you created '6am to 18pm' while you have 7 in duration. is it expected?

Comment: @Ben.T Yes it is always 6to18 and 18to6. Yeah just ignore that, there are some seconds that my code is round up to the next minute.

Comment: @mm_nieder I asked this because you could calculate the 18to6 by doing `df['18pm to 6am'] = df['duration'] - df['6am to 18pm']` but if you have round up, it might not be a good way ..

Comment: @mm_nieder otherwise, in your code, for `check_time_2`, in the `return`, if you replace `&` (and) by `|` (or) it should work better because the hour is either under 6 or above 18, can't be both like in `check_time` where it has to be both above 6 and under 18

Comment: @Ben.T hmm would it work better if I restructured it like 6:00to17:59 and 18:00to5:59?

Comment: @mm_nieder I don't think it will make a difference, you already use `>=` or `<` which sould do it

Comment: @Ben.T It worked by switching `&` by `|`. If you would like to post the answer and I will upvote you answer:) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, for `check_time_2`, if you replace `&` (and) by `|` (or), it should work better because the hour is either under 6 or above 18 and can't be both like in `check_time`, where it has to be both above 6 and under 18. So your function `check_time_2` should be:

```
def check_time_2(df_line):
    max_hours = float(df_line['max time']) # not sure it's necessary actually...
    dt_range = pd.date_range(start = df_line['Parked_from'], end=df_line['Parked_to'], freq='1Min')
    return np.sum((dt_range.hour >= (df_line['Start_Enforce_2'])) | (dt_range.hour < df_line['Finish_Enforce_2']))
```

Comment: Is it possible to replicate this using `df_line['Start_Enforce_2'] = 11` and  `df_line['Finish_Enforce_2'] = 10`?  If so I'll post a question!

Comment: @mm_nieder not sure what you mean but if your point is to use different values in `'Start_Enforce_2'` and `'Finish_Enforce_2'` than 6 and 18, the method should work, as you go read the value in these columns in your function

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I figured it out. But yes I was wanting to use different values 11 and 10